# Set cursor location in CompletionItem

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add numbers to the sass-indentation extension and I kind of figured out how to that, it would be nice if i could set the cursor location when the suggestion gets triggered, just like you can set the cursor location when you make snippets with `$1`, is that possible ?

```ts
import { CompletionItem, CompletionItemKind } from 'vscode';

const sassSchemaTest = [
  {
    name: '%',
    body: '$1%', // I want the cursor location where the '$' sign is
    description: 'test'
  }
];

export default sassSchemaTest.map(item => {
  const completionItem = new CompletionItem(item.name);
  completionItem.insertText = item.body;
  completionItem.detail = item.description;
  completionItem.kind = CompletionItemKind.Property;

  return completionItem;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, completion items support the [usual snippet syntax](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). Simply use a [`vscode.SnippetString`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SnippetString) for [`insertText`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.insertText) instead of a raw `string`.

> A string **or snippet** that should be inserted in a document when selecting this completion. When `falsy` the [label](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.label) is used.

```ts
completionItem.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString(item.body);
```